# Git push New in Renesas E2 Studio

Tags: git, eclipse, embedded, renesas-rx

I have project that i worked on for some time in renesas E2 studio, and I want to push that to Git and be able to pull to clone in other systems connected to my git server.
I tried the create master repository option, clone options but so far didn't work. Anyone who worked with renesas or git could help me out?

Answer (score 0):

sure, here is the way :)

Create a remote Git repository:
You'll need to have a remote Git repository to which you can push your project. This could be a repository hosted on a service like GitHub, GitLab, or Bitbucket, or it could be a local repository on your computer that you plan to share with others.

Configure EGit in e² studio:
EGit is the Git plugin for Eclipse, and it will be used to manage your Git repository in e² studio. To configure EGit, follow these steps:

a. In e² studio, go to Window > Preferences.
b. In the Preferences dialog, expand the Egit tree and select Git Repositories.
c. In the Git Repositories page, select Add Existing Local Repository.
d. Browse to the directory containing your Renesas E2 Studio project and click Finish.

Stage your changes:
Before you can push your changes to the remote repository, you need to stage them. This means telling Git which files you want to include in the next commit. To stage your changes, follow these steps:

a. In e² studio, go to the Project Explorer and select the folder containing your Renesas E2 Studio project.
b. In the Git Staging view, click Refresh.
c. Select the files that you want to stage for commit.
d. Click Add selected files to the index.

Add a commit message:
A commit message is a brief description of the changes that you have made to your project. To add a commit message, follow these steps:

a. In the Git staging view, click Commit message.
b. In the Commit Dialog, enter a commit message and click Commit.

Push your changes to the remote repository:
Once you have staged and committed your changes, you can push them to the remote repository. To push your changes, follow these steps:

a. In the Push Result... dialog, click Close.

Now your project is pushed to the remote Git repository and accessible to other systems connected to your Git server. They can pull the latest changes from the repository and clone the project to their own computers.